# What's the meaning & story behind this `Streisand`?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

I saw following paragraph from: https://basecamp.com/gettingreal/16.1-start-your-engines

> You need people who are passionate about what they do. People who care
>   about their craft — and actually think of it as a craft. People who
>   take pride in their work, regardless of the monetary reward involved.
>   People who sweat the details even if 95% of folks don’t know the
>   difference. People who want to build something great and won’t settle
>   for less. People who need people. **OK, not really that last one but we
>   couldn’t resist throwing a little Streisand into the mix.** Anyhow, when
>   you find those people, hold onto them. In the end, the folks on your
>   team will make or break your project — and your company.

Regarding the sentence in **bold** above, it seems like a joke for me, but I failed to understand its background, even after googling.
So, what is this `Streisand` stands for, and what story is behind ?

Comment: Barbra Streisand sang a song starting "People. People who need people."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question; it's one for Music Fans.SE.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Got it !

Comment: No, it's a valid question. If OP knew what it meant, and that it was a musical reference, he wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about English at all - it's about an obscure ***cultural*** reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's far from obscure.  It was adopted into the Grammy Hall of Fame and rated #13 in a list of 100 most popular songs in the past 100 years in 2004.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fPlQ6EtArSc